# Style specific element if display equal to block with smooth animation JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I use this code from [W3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible) for my collapsible sections, it works well and now I want to slide down "Open Section 1 Button" (margin-top: 10px) if the first section "Open Section 1 Content" is hidden (display none). I knew and understand that this is a very simple task but a new to JS and it is hard for me to figure it out how to apply css dimamicaly only if certain conditions are met (and revert it back margin-top:0 if display block).

As I say I had tried different approaches and they mess with the original W3 JS code,it is stoped working if I applied something else with display mentioning on top of it.

I need to target only **one** element **if** only one of them is changes his status (display block - to none; none - to block).

And if it is possible I would like add some animation while element is moving up and down

Also it will be nice if **all** collapsible section equal to display none the script will activate another hidden div (not mentioned before) with an image and hide it if **any** of this section are equal to display block.

Any help will be appreciated

(I have three collapsible, as well as a three button for each one, just as simple as at the W3 example)

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function that will set the first section's `margin-top` to `10px` if its nextElementSibling's display is not block and execute the function on page load and on showing the content. To make the element animate the margin-top smoothly, you can add `transition: margin 0.5s` to `.collapsible`.

```css
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: margin 0.5s;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<p>Collapsible Set:</p>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 2</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<button class="collapsible">Open Section 3</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
        }
        moveSection();
    });
}
function moveSection(){
  var section1 = coll[0];
  if(section1.nextElementSibling.style.display!="block"){
    section1.style.marginTop = "10px";
  } else {
    section1.style.marginTop = "";
  }
}
moveSection();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```